# what do we mean with IPC performance

Tags: performance, sockets, ipc, instruction-set

I saw material illustrating a 6% core single thread IPC performance increase from one generation of some hardware to the next. Does it mean that the number of instructions per cycle increases by 6%? What is exactly IPC performance?

Comment: It would help if you provided a reference to the *"material"*.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instructions_per_cycle